# Updating database table based on condition set in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, inner-join

How would I set a condition between 2 tables?

1 table has IDs whose values that need to be changed based on values set in another table.

The query I have so far...no idea if it works.

`UPDATE table1 set value='2' INNER JOIN table2 WHERE CONVERT(value USING utf8) LIKE '%text%')` so when value is 2 in the first table, that same item in table 2 will be assigned a specific category. The query should check that the ID in table 2 is the same ID that it found in table 1 that contained the value.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.  Your join doesn't have an `ON` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff using mysql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like MySQL.  If so, the correct syntax is more like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON t1.id = t2.id
    set t1.value = '2' 
WHERE CONVERT(t1.value USING utf8) LIKE '%text%');
```

Your question is a bit vague on the actual `JOIN` conditions, but that is the structure of the query.

Comment: table 1 is the condition and table 2 will be the data that gets updated.  When the value of an ID in table 1 contains a certain text, that ID in table will be set to a specific value in table 2.  so if 200 rows in table 1 contain the text I need, then 200 rows in table 2 will be changed. why do you have `table1 t1` and `table2 t2` in your query?  why not just `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: had to correct the column names but the query worked (using the names of my database tables of course).